# Avoid duplicating syslog messages into /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, rsyslog

I'm using the following rsyslog configuration file to redirect logs of a program to a specific file.

```
# Name of the program
set $.program_name = "myapp";

# Path to the log file
set $.logfile_path = "/var/log/myapp.log";

# Templates 
$template log_file, "%$.logfile_path%"
$template datetime_message, "[%timestamp:::date-year%-%timestamp:::date-month%-%timestamp:::date-day%_%timestamp:::date-hour%_%timestamp:::date-minute%_%timestamp:::date-second%.%timestamp:0:3:date-subseconds%]%msg%\n"

# Program log redirection
if( ($programname == $.program_name)) then
{
    ?log_file;datetime_message
}
```

Since I don't have a lot of storage available and that the program generates a lot of logs, the file is regularly rotated using logrotate, compressed and then sent to a server with a large storage capacity so the partition mounted on `/var` never saturates.

It was working pretty well until I realized that even if logs are redirected to the file they are also sent into `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/user.log`.

So the logs are duplicated into four different files, with three of them not being rotated regularly, thus leading to a partition saturation pretty fast.

I searched for a way to send logs only to `/var/log/myapp.log` but I didn't find anything. Also I would like to avoid modifying `/etc/rsyslog.conf`  and only modify the specific rsyslog configuration file located at `/etc/rsyslog.d/99-myapp.conf`.

How could I tell syslog that all logs from `myapp` shall be sent only into `/var/log/myapp.log` and not in any other file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having selected a message, and provided an action for it, you can stop
further processing of that message by adding the `stop` action:

```
if( ($programname == $.program_name)) then
{
    ?log_file;datetime_message
    stop
}
```

This can be done in your file if is included from the main config file (for example, with
`$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`) *before* any other actions, which
is normally the case.
Look for the word "discard" in the [documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/basic_structure.html).